# Is there a collective term to refer to these keywords?

Tags: javascript

Is there a collective term to refer to these keywords (maybe something that's used in documentation?)?:
`const`
`let`
`var`
`implicit` e.g. `x = 5`.

I've been calling them identifier keywords.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) those are mentioned under declarations. Its a good read.

Comment: As you *declare* a variable with something like `let x` it makes sense to call `let` a declaration. Good eye @Tejeshree!